# Can't scan the QR code by com.codename1.ext.codescan.CodeScanner

Tags: codenameone

I often can't read QR code by com.codename1.ext.codescan.CodeScanner on Android and iOS.
Is there any other better codescanner library for codename1?
For exapmle, the attached QR code image(shown on screen) can be recognized on iOS and Android.
But the printed QRcode image(small size) can't be read both on iOS and Android.
I think codescanner can only read large QR code image but small.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Android we also have the little monkey QR but it's only an extension on top of the existing library and specific to Android.

We have this: https://github.com/shannah/cn1-codescan-scandit

Which is portable but also relatively pricey. It's far more reliable and faster than other options.

Comment: I am curious that the library page describes

Platform Support
Currently iOS and Android are supported.

Can the library be used on iOS?

Comment: Yes. You specifically mentioned iOS. Was this a typo?

Comment: Because of your mention "specific to Android".
I will try the library.
Thank you.

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry for the confusion. That's another library called little monkey: https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/QRScanner it's cross platform too but will only change the behavior on Android: https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/QRScanner

Comment: It's free and open source. But won't solve your iOS issues.